# Printer Problems: Epson-Stylus-NX420

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, epson

I am new to Linux. I have heard one of the drawbacks to Linux is the peripheral support. I automatically installed my Epson Stylus NX420 using the "add printer" feature. It was super easy and I was thrilled to prove that Ubuntu defied the typical stereotype of printer support issues, or so I thought. I tried to print something and the printer went absolutely crazy. It spit out page after page, until I finally just unplugged it. I am curious to know if there is a driver out there that can correct this issue. I am using the 12.04 distro.

Thanks,

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16875&DSCCHK=a9c4fba46743be0cb2d94aa2fb14ff87ac792dcf

You will want the .deb file. Select the i386 version if you have a 32-bit system and x86_64 if yours is a 64-bit system. Check:

```
arch
```

After the file is downloaded, you should be able to right-click it and install it with Software Center.